# Silently Reactivation of a closed user

Tags: docusignapi

lHello,

I need to silently reactivate closed users. I tried using the same JSON I use to create active users (https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/how-to/create-active-user), but with the UID of the closed user, but did not work. How can I do it?

Regards
Lórien

Comment: Do you have the DocuSign Admin functionality? central management of accounts and users for your organization?

Answer (score 0):

Since this initial answer was posted, there's been some progress. Automatic Activation no longer requires sending the activation email. See Step 2 below.

In order for this process to succeed in activating the user, they must be under a claimed domain with "Auto-activate manually added memberships and suppress activation emails" set.

This is only doable through the Admin API. The eSignature API *can* reactivate a user, but it requires them to click the email they receive.

0. Generate an auth token with user_write and user_read permissions
1. Find the user/membership in question. In order to do so, you must make the GetUsers call with the account_id parameter and page through to find the user in question and capture the membership ID

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/reference/users/users/getusers/

Example Call:

```
GET /organizations/[[Org_Id]]/users?account_id=[[AccountId]]&take=20&start=0

Response includes:
        {
            "id": "9672a992-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-8fb5c4b6d325",
            "user_name": "Example User"
            "first_name": "Example",
            "last_name": "User",
            "membership_status": "closed",
            "email": "user@example.com",
            "membership_created_on": "2021-01-1T10:10:10.10",
            "membership_id": "b5283dfb-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-eb0aeac16b8c"
        },
```

- to page, look at the "paging" : { "next" } parameter to see the start / take values to use for the repeat call
- At time of writing, getUsers with the Email Address parameter does NOT return the membership ID for the user's memberships
- Furthermore, getUsers by email does not list closed memberships

2. use UpdateUser call to activate

Documentation: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/reference/users/users/updateuser/

Example Call:

> POST /organizations/[[Org_Id]]/users/profiles

> ```
> {
>     "auto_activate_memberships_on_reactivation": "true", 
>     "users": [
>         {
>             "id": "9672a992-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-8fb5c4b6d325",
>             "site_id": 1,
>             "memberships": [
>                 {
>                     "account_id": "182e8dd4-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-594834882eab",
>                     "send_activation": true
>                 }
>             ]
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

In Demo, site_id is always 1. In Prod, site ID will depend on where the account is hosted.

**Step 3 should no longer be required, but I'm leaving this here for reference:**

3. Activate user's membership using the membership ID

Documentation: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/reference/users/users/activatemembership/

> POST /organizations/[[org_id]]/users/[[user_id]]/memberships/[[membership_id]]

> ```
> {
> "site_id":"1"
> }
> ```